# What would the weather be like on an earth like planet the size of Jupiter?

Tags: planets, gravity, weather, seasons

Let’s get this out of the way: yes, I have considered the fact that there would be a massive gravity difference, but I have figured out a way around it. (It’s implausible in our reality, but works for this one)
So going from there: Assuming it would have the same gravity but a much larger surface area, how would the weather change?
Would seasons be more extreme due to a slightly further distance from the sun? What could other implications be? This is a vague idea, and I’m just looking for feasible ideas and ramifications.

Comment: since you don't tell us how you solved the gravity problem this is pure opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**Would seasons be more extreme due to a slightly further distance from the sun?**

Nope. Not to any noticeable degree. That's not what causes seasonal variation. Seasons are caused by changing *angles* to the sun, which cause the same amount of light to be spread out over a larger or smaller surface area. As long as the axial tilt is the same, seasons would work exactly the same; the climate zones would just be much larger.

If the rotation period is the same and Earth's, then Coriolis forces would be weaker, due to the slower rate of change of spin radius vs. latitude. You should end up with a similar 3-cell-per-hemisphere major circulation system, with each cell covering a larger area. That would give cyclonic storms (hurricanes and typhoons) more room to wander around once they have formed, and thus potentially considerably longer average lifespans, but the reduced strength of Coriolis forces would make it more difficult for them to form in the first place.

If this planet also has an Earthlike moon, the tidal effects across the larger planetary radius would be stronger. The same goes for solar tides.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider clarification on the amount of liquid at the surface for several weather affects. The tides don't actually move in and out, the solid earth rotates through a tidal bulge. This has more to do the gravitational significance and placement of any moons and the star(s) than the actual size of the planet itself. The Coriolis effect would be proportionally different based off of how fast the planet spun. If your attempt is to make time proportionally 1:1 with earth time then the spin would need to be increased such that per unit rotation the same amount of observable time passes. I think this would make the change in the constellation position much more noticeable. Also, consider the placement of the large planet within the goldilocks zone of the star system. A more massive planet would likely need to be further away to prevent falling into the star. This would increase the length of the solar year significantly.

On another note. As you increase the mass of one solar object, you decrease the amount of mass available for other objects to form. The number of observable planets would likely be different depending on what life cycle the star system was on. For example a second generation star would be living off the unburnt fuel from the previous hyper-star and the resulting size of the star would be decreased, however it is improbable to have celestial objects orbiting a first generation star. As the number of star generations proceed, the ambient amount of sub-iron matter decreases and the "fuel" for the star also decreases. I think everything up to iron is fusible within a star given the right amount of "fuel" but everything after iron requires a nova. That definitely needs some fact check. Regardless, as you increase the amount of mass in your planet you decrease the mass available for the star(for sub-iron matter) to function and other objects to form (sub and post iron)

Comment: The size of the planet has absolutely nothing to do with the size of its orbit. A planet of any size can go anywhere.

Comment: 99.8% of the solar system's mass is in the sun.  You could make Earth a hundred times more massive, and the sun would not have appreciably "less mass available" for it.

Comment: While size has nothing to do with orbit, mass does. Gravitational forces between two objects are directly linked to their mass and distance. Planets of any size cannot go anywhere, otherwise there would be nothing explicitly keep earth in orbit.

Comment: While yes the ratio of mass between the earth and sun is rather one sided this isn't explicitly true for a 5th or 6th generation star.

Comment: Yes, gravitational forces are directly linked to mass-which is precisely why orbital acceleration is *invariant* to mass to an extremely high degree of precision. So yes, you can put a planet of any size in any orbit and it won't fall into the sun--and we have in fact *found* exoplanets of arbitrary sizes in arbitrarily close orbits, which proves definitively that larger planets in smaller orbits *won't* magically fall into the star just because they are larger.